# How to write a file using Codeigniter File Helper

Tags: php, file, codeigniter

I want to write a class and save it into `application/models/` folder.

The code is as below:-

```
function writeANewFile()
{
$path = "/LMSV1/application/models/";
$classname = "firstidgenerator";
$this->load->helper('file');
$data = "<?php class ".$classname." extends CI_Model {
function generateId(\$db)
{
\$data['orders'] = 'orders';
 \$this->\$db->trans_start();
 \$this->\$db->insert('$classname', \$data);
 \$insert_id = \$this->\$db->insert_id();
 \$this->\$db->trans_complete();
return \$insert_id;
} 
} ";

$result = write_file(''.$path.''.$classname.'.php', $data);
echo json_encode($result);
} //end fucntion
```

If i give the `$path = "c:/xampp/htdocs/FrameWorks/LMSV1/application/models/";` then it successfully saves a file in desired folder.

But if if i give `$path = "/LMSV1/application/models/";` then it returns false and does not create a file.

The problem lies in setting path and i could not successfully figure out what should be the path to be given as parameter?

Answer (score 2):

Codeigniter has a few path constants that are useful in this case. The constant `APPPATH` is what you need.

```
$path = APPPATH . "models/";
```

Comment: I just want to know one another thing. Will this code work on Live Server?

Comment: Yes. The constant is based on the installation path and the location of the index.php file. It is completely portable.